# how to list or remove a service, a page in ionic2?

Tags: ionic2

I know how to generate a service in ionic2:

```
ionic g provider myservice
```

is there anyway to list all pages or services in ionic2? or remove a specific service?

Or I just do it manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can't do it through Ionic CLI, but you can list it simply in file tree:

- **/app/pages/** for pages
- **/app/providers/** for providers (services)
- **/app/components/** for components and directives (it's better to separate it)
- **/app/pipes/** for pipes

For remove some service/page (etc.) you have to do it manually or use some smart IDE with searching dependencies (e. g. WebStorm).